# linear accelerometer stability ? android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am using the linear accelerometer to detect shaking, I am using this code:

```
            float x = event.values[0] ;
            float y = event.values[1] ;
            float z = event.values[2] ;
            float acceleration = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
            if(acceleration > 5)
            {
               Toast.makeText(this,"shaking",Toast.Length_long).show();
             }
```

the problem is when I shake the device, the acceleration become 10 for example, but when I stop shaking the device the acceleration doesn't return to zero immediately, it takes some seconds !

```
             -      shaking the device          -               no shaking              -
acceleration =    20 19 22 23 24 20 24  25 30   - 19 18 17 15 13 0000000000             -
```

why this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The linear acceleration that you used is a synthetic (as opposed to physical) sensor type. That means its "readings" are derived from the physical accelerometer readings, which of course contains both the linear acceleration motion and the gravity components. Basically these two components are separated by using filters. For example, a low-pass filter only admits slow changing signals (like gravity) and attenuates fast changing signals (like the shaking motion). Depending on the actual design of filters, they usually have latencies in terms of response time, which is the delay you experienced.

If you want to reduce the delay, try directly using the raw physical accelerometer readings and implementing your own high-pass filter to get rid of the gravity component. You can try using higher order filters, which reduces the delay, but at the expense of introducing artifacts. I've had good experience using the [Butterworth filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter), if you'd like something to try first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Accel data we get on Application/Driver level:

1. Filtered Accel data (generally moving average or IIR filter)
2. Un-filtered Accel data

Any sudden change in the Accel will not be observed on filtered data since it takes few sample or time to stabilize.
But you can observe sudden change with Unfiltered data.

Unfiltered data will get utilize for use cases like Free-fall, Shake detection.
Filtered data will be get utilize for use cases like slow/moderate motions like lid angle detection etc.